# Finding non existing fields from an array in another array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-2.7, dynamic-arrays

I'm writing a code that has 2 python arrays, `svslist` and `prlist`. For the purposes of this task, I'm supposed to be finding values that exist in the `svslist` array but not in the `prlist` array.

So far I've come up with a solution that shows the fields that exist in both. What I actually want to accomplish is to figure out the fields that exist in the `svslist` array but not the `prlist` array.

Additionally I also want to find out fields that exist in the `prlist` array but not in the `svslist` array. I've kept out the code that actually populates the two arrays for simplicity purposes. Can somebody please shed insight on how I'm supposed to be doing this?

Here's a snippet of my code so far:

```py
import os
import json

svslist=[]
prlist=[]
count=0

print("FIELDS IN SVS:",x)
print("FIELDS IN Profile:",y)
print("\n")

svslist=list(dict.fromkeys(svslist))
prlist=list(dict.fromkeys(prlist))


x=(len(svslist))
y=(len(prlist))


print("FIELDS IN SVS AFTER CLEANUP:",x)
print("FIELDS IN Profile AFTER CLEANUP:",y)
print("\n")

for q in range(x):
    for w in range(y):
        if svslist[q]==prlist[w]:
            count=count+1
            print(svslist[q]," exists in Profile")
        else:
            continue
print("\nTotal",count,"fields from SVS exist in Profile")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through your SVS list, and check for each entry if it exists in Profile, using the 'in' statement. Likewise, you can use the else statement to extract the values that are not in your prlist:

```
count = 0
svs_only = []
for i in range(len(svslist)):
    if svslist[i] in prlist:
        count += 1
        print(svslist[i]," exists in Profile")
    else:
        svs_only.append(svslist[i])
print("\nTotal",count,"fields from SVS exist in Profile")
print("\nSVS Fields not present in Profile:",svs_only)
```